# Artefacts in topology of imported SVG

Tags: topology, svg

I've exported design from Illustrator to Inkscape to turn it in SVG and then make a model in blender. I've traced bitmap in Inkscape and everything seemed fine but when I click edit mode in blender - object appears with strange artefacts in topology coming from holes of an object. How do I fix this?

[image]

[image]

I've tried to voxel remesh as well but objects becomes too small and nothing really changes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: No problem save svg directly from Illustrator. For this shape you can keep object as curve object instead of converting to mesh. Than adjust Depth in curve properties. Probably if you can share your blend via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @vklidu There it is, hope you will find a way to sort this, because when I paste it later to substance painter/keyshot - there's a complete mess with a model. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=JsQyVLz7" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/JsQyVLz7/)

Comment: For a simple shape like that just delete all of the faces, keep the outer edges, and re-create them in blender using proper modeling techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If object has mostly straight angles that need to be traced:

- Create curve->Right click->Set spline type->Poly-> Just keep clicking E to extrude individual points. Because Object itself consists mostly of straight angles, its easier to do that.

2. If object need to have round angles in the end model:

- Create curve->Right click->Set spline type->Poly-> Just keep clicking E to extrude individual points->CTRL+SHIFT+B on vertices in edit mode for accessing vertices bevelling.

Answer (score 0):

Overlapping or intersecting paths in SVG do not translate well to blender, as they end up being different planes on top of each other. In the vector editing software use boolean operations (union, difference, intersect, exclusion, etc.) to clean up. those overlaps. Then export as SVG and import to blender.

See [Complex SVG file fails to import correctly into Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208965/complex-svg-file-fails-to-import-correctly-into-blender/209043#209043)