# CTRL+J Changes my imported svg file

Tags: mesh, groups

I imported an SVG file and when I do <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> it changes my images, it crops it. The image that says "Just Play" is before <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> and the cropped one is after.

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?[image] [image]

Comment: Avoid intersecting and overlapping shapes. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208965/complex-svg-file-fails-to-import-correctly-into-blender/209043#209043

Comment: A crucial difference between 3d graphics and 2D illustration is that in 3D you can't have surfaces occupying the same plane. You have two choices: separate the objects slightly so that they are in different planes, or re-work your original paths in whatever program you used to create the svg files and create paths that don't overlap or intersect.